# How can I prevent an ImageView from resizing to fit the screen programmatically?

Tags: java, android, imageview

I am making a 2D platformer type game. I made a `ImageView` using JAVA, that Is **supposed** to be about twice the size of the screen horizontally.

However, when the `ImageView` is displayed no matter the size of the Image, it keeps re-sizing to fit my screen . Note that I am not using XML, but I am purely using JAVA. **How can I prevent this?**

Here is the code:

```
    ConstraintLayout gameLayout;
    gameLayout = findViewById(R.id.gameLayout);


    ImageView map = new ImageView(this);
    map.setImageResource(R.drawable.tutorial_map);
    map.setX(0);
    map.setY(0);
    gameLayout.addView(map);
```

Feel free to edit further if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);`

or

You can also use `map.setAdjustViewBounds(true);`

Make sure you use `map.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tutorial_map)` instead of `map.setImageResource(R.drawable.tutorial_map).`

Comment: None of these seem to be working for me. When I try to make my map bigger (MS paint) they just would not show up at all. (Meaby this has to do with the other code I put in, so this may be correct) Edit: Would you like me to provide a screen shot?

Comment: Maybe you should try with set background rather than set imager resource.

Comment: use this map.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tutorial_map);

Comment: Once again, none of these work. I will do an edit showing some screenshots of the thing. Are you testing these out, or just relying on memory? Cause, if you are testing them, this meaby another unrealted problem with my code.

Comment: I have edited my question adding ScreenShots of my  android device with your sollutions.

Comment: Nah i got same problem before and this helped me.

Comment: Can you show your xml file where are you trying to set this view? May be something is there.

Comment: I figured it out. The reason the image cannot display is beacuse in the XML, the Constraint layout are set to fit the screen. I adjusted things. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to hear this. 
Happy coding..!

Answer (score 0):

What framework are you using to build the game. My suggestion would be to use libgdx which is super lightweight, cross platform and awesome. Trust me this question will be the least of your problems. As a developer, you need to think of how your code is going to change tomorrow. 
So, since you are using an imageview, just set as fixed the width of your window and scale your imageview as you wish. Cheers!

Comment: For this project, I will be only using Android and Java without any pulg-ins. Thanks for the suggestion though :)